# SQL Query Create isDuplicate Column with IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 database I'm working with. For the query I am using, I want to add a custom column that can start at any number and increment based on the row entry number.

For example, I start at number 10. Each row in my results will have an incrementing number 10, 11, 12, etc..

This is an example of the SELECT statement I would be using.

```
int customVal = 10;

SELECT 
    ID, customVal++ 
FROM myTable
```

The format of the above is clearly wrong, but it is conceptually what I am looking for.

RESULTS:

```
 ID     CustomColumn
 -------------------
 1         10
 2         11
 3         12
 4         13
```

How can I go about implementing this kind functionality?

I cannot find any reference to incrementing variables within results. Is this the case?

EDIT: The `customVal` number will be pulled from another table. I.e. probably do a `Select` statement into the `customVal` variable. You cannot assume the the ID column will be any usable values.

The `CustomColumn` will be auto-incrementing starting at the `customVal`.

Comment: You mean add a custom column to the table itself or to the query?

Comment: Just the query itself.  Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Where do you get the 'any' number from ? Hardcoded, other table, variable, ... ? As far as I understand the question you _simply_ want `SELECT ID, CustomColumn = 10 + ID - 1 FROM myTable` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the ROW_NUMBER ranking function - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx

```
DECLARE @Offset INT = 9

SELECT
     ID
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) + @Offset
FROM
    Table
```

Comment: Didn't consider the fact that you could just add to the ROW_NUMBER() function.  I think this will work perfectly.

Comment: Don't forget to deduct 1 again as Row_Number() is 1-based =)